# custom service created via ambari stack not appearing on ambari UI dashboard

Tags: apache

I created a custom service and added it to the Ambari stack. I can view the service as registered and installed via REST APIs.

Is there a way to have that service appear on the ambari UI so the Ops person can configure from the UI rather than REST calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to this question, but anyways, your service will not show up if you have an Ambari version lower than 1.7.0.

There is a guide from the Ambari people here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38571133.

I also posted a tutorial regarding Ambari Stacks here: http://bit.ly/1HDBgS6

Hope that helps.